# "mysqli_real_escape_string" is working but control is not entering into second if block

Tags: php

Following program i picked from the php site (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) and ran on my system running wamp server.
I found that escape charecter is getting added but control is not getting inside 2nd if block

Here's the code:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin", "sampdb");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
}

mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City");

$city = "'s Hertogenbosch";

/* this query will fail, cause we didn't escape $city */
if (!mysqli_query($link, "INSERT into myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_sqlstate($link));
}

 $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $city);
print $city;

/* this query with escaped $city will work */
if (mysqli_query($link, "INSERT into myCity (Name) VALUES ('$city')")) {
        printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_affected_rows($link));
}

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

O/P :

Error: 42000

\'s Hertogenbosch

As per example mentioned in the link : "http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php" the control should enter into the second if block and print number of rows inserted. which is not happening in this case.

Comment: Are you asking why there is a \ before the ' still? If not, what do you get versus what you expect?

Comment: Try calling `mysqli_error` instead of `mysqli_sqlstate`, the former gives you a description of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape character is *added* by the `mysqli_real_escape_string` function, that's it purpose. Escaping means putting the escape character (in SQL, it's a backslash) before control characters like the apostrophe (').

Comment: when escape charecter added i should get the message ".. Row inserted" as specified in the link mentioned above. But the control is not going inside the if block. Not getting output as mentioned in the link "http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php"

Comment: The `mysqli_insert` call with the `INSERT` statement returns `false`. To see what actually went wrong, I would call `mysqli_error` instead of `mysqli_sqlstate`, as I commented on your question.

Comment: I have used mysqli_error and got the descriptive message : "Error: Table 'sampdb.mycity' doesn't exist"... the table itself not created. "mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myCity LIKE City");"

Comment: Ok, then Hamikzo was right. You can't create a temporary table. Maybe the table `City` - of which the temporary table `myCity` should be a copy - doesn't exist? You should create a real table e.g. with phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

The error you got is coming from first query run. Try to comment that first block and see if it runs smoothly. It should run.

Comment: It won't run when the table `myCity` doesn't exist - and I think, it doesn't. But as seen now, you're right with your first sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The point of mysqli_real_escape_string is to add backslashes before unsafe characters. So it will turn ' into \' , " into \" etc... It does this to make your SQL string safe for the database.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqli_real_escape_string()` is not about removing unwanted characters. It returns strings, where each character having special meaning (an apostrophe in your case) prefixed by backslash (the escape character).

By escaping you can insert those special characters into text-fields in your database. To quote the page, characters prefixed  are: `NUL` (ASCII 0), `\n`, `\r`, `\`, `'`, `"`, and `Control-Z`.